# Translating Python to C

Tags: python, c, arrays, intervals, language-translation

I have an important project to write but there is a problem: I have to do it in C from Python (I absolutely do not know well Python..)

I've translated almost 70% of the code but because of one line of code I can't complete it so I really hope for someone to help me..

here is the line in question:

```
define1 = '\x0F\x10\x20\xD6'

def function(file):
  if file[i:i+4] == define1:
    [...]
```

(with `file` which is supposed to be a binary), and I absolutely don't know how write this `file[i:i+4]` in C (I assume it can be done using arrays and pointers but that's all...).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are dealing with slicing. ```file[i:i+4]``` extracts subarray of length 4 at position ```i```.  You do not need to extract it in c so you can compare memory regions in place without extracting it into extra variable ```if(memcmp(file + i, define1, 4) == 0)```

Comment: In the future please try to write a better title. Questions asking for code to be translated get closed and deleted all the time, and at first your question might appear to fall into that category. But you know what you want to ask: "I absolutely don't know how write this `file[i:i+4]` in C". I suspect you can come up with a better title from there.

Comment: thank you !! I'm sorry here is a last question: I have to addition it like `binary[:i] + file[i:i+4] + define1`, what's the translation here ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment but to help answer your question for

```
binary[:i] + file[i:i+4] + define1
```

When you see list_name[:number], it still slicing but when you don't see a start index it means start from the beginning, and end at some index in the list. The index it stops on is excluded.

So what this line is doing is just it is creating a one long binary. For example...

```
x = b'1001'
y = b'0110'
z = b'0111'

# takes the first two bits of x, the two middle bits of y, and all of the bits of z.
x[:2] + y[1:3] + z = b'10110111'
```

Hope this helps :)